# Android intent filter - React Native 0.70

Tags: react-native, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to launch a custom react native app from the Community Health Toolkit [(CHT App Launcher)](https://docs.communityhealthtoolkit.org/apps/reference/forms/app/#android-app-launcher). The goal is that a button is pressed in CHT and that the user is then forwarded directly to the custom app.

I am using the below code right now for my custom react native app in the AndroidManifest.xml file to launch it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter  android:label="string resource">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
 <queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <!-- If you don't know the MIME type in advance, set "mimeType" to "*/*". -->
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
   </intent>
 </queries>
```

However, I have difficulties launching the react native app from CHT even though both apps are installed on the emulator. CHT works in such a way that we can define an intent directly in the xlsx form. Currently, we use the following format in the xlsx default column to start the react native app “**android.intent.action.VIEW**”.

Unfortunately, the custom app does not appear when we press the button on CHT.
The preview window just prompts me to open other apps (e.g., Adobe Reader etc..).

If I define another intent in the xlsx form in CHT such as "**android.media.action.image_capture**", the standard camera app on the emulator opens successfully.

As a result, I believe I misdefined something in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your intent-filter must be like

```
 <intent-filter android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="app.applinking" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The android:scheme must be your app linking URL.

Comment: I specified the app linking url as follows: "org.medicmobile.webapp.mobile"  [(CHT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.medicmobile.webapp.mobile) . Unfortunately, the app still does not open or does not appear in the suggestions.

Comment: Please check if your package name is correct and can you please share the GitHub repo to reproduce the error?